# Serve gzipped content via a Web Resource

Tags: http-headers, dynamics-crm, gzip

I have a Dynamics 365 instance that makes heavy use of custom front-end interfaces using a modern Nodejs-based build pipeline involving the usual suspects such as webpack/babel/etc. I'm hosting these files as webresources in Dynamics (one html file and one bundle.js file per SPA).

As my team nears production, I'm trying to set up a nice production build for our front-end stuff to reduce load times. Unfortunately, I can't find a good way to serve our bundle.js files encoded as gzip because Dynamics does not return the `Content-Encoded: gzip` header when a request is made and therefore the browser doen't decompress the file and tries to read the compressed file as plain JavaScript.

Of course, we can serve the uncompressed file just fine but we would like to provide the smaller, faster loading file if possible as it's generally about 1/3 the size.

Does anyone have any brilliant ideas for how to override the default response headers coming back from dynamics when I request a web resource? Or any other clever solutions to this problem?

Thanks, and let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to serve gzipped content via a web resource.

If the download size is a huge concern perhaps encode the gzipped code to base64 and store it as a string variable in JS. 
Then during execution you could decode, unzip, and `eval()` the code.

You could also store base64 gzipped code as a file attachment via an annotation record or within an XML web resource, though those options would require an additional API call to get the code, so a string variable may be your best bet.

Comment: The JS string option is probably the best bet. For my use case I think it's best if I leave out gzip altogether and just served the slightly larger (~200 kb) file. I'll accept this answer because it does solve the problem. Thanks!